# Relay modern + GraphQL + found-relay - transformation before child gets a fragment

Tags: routes, relayjs, relaymodern

I want to build a simple routing where my Table component receives the fragment **Table_table**:

*routing.js*

```
const tableQuery = graphql`
    query routesTableQuery($tableId: String){
    store {
        table(id: $tableId){
            name
            stake
        }
    }}
`

<Route
    path="table"
    Component={Table}
    prepareVariables={params => ({tableId: '59abf1a01710ba3b74718220'})}
    query={tableQuery}
/>
```

*Table.js container*

```
export default createFragmentContainer(
Table,
graphql`
    fragment Table_table on Table {
        name
        stake
    }
)`
```

But instead of receiving **table** prop in the component, I'm receiving **store** (and table prop is null). Also if I set **...Table_table** instead of specific fields inside the query, I'm getting an error "Expected prop `table` to be supplied to `Relay(Table)`, but got `undefined`" Any thoughts why?

Answer (score 0):

I managed it by using **render** attribute in the routing.

```
render={({Component, props})=>{
    return <Component table={props.store.table} />
}}
```